# Let $A$ be the event that the share price never moves up. Find, with a justification, the probability of $A$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In the share price model which is a random experiment depicting the evolution of share price at random fixed time intervals where the probability of the price going up or down at time $t=n$ where n is a natural number is the same. Let $A$ be the event that the share price
never moves up. Find, with a justification, the probability of $A$.

This question is on a past exam paper of a measure theory course I'm taking. I know that the answer is that the probability is $0$ but I'm not quite sure how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There must be some background describing share price movement.  Otherwise a scenario without movement is quite possible.

Comment: “The share price movement example” is not some fundamental example that is universally known by everyone (or anyone).

Comment: I see you edited to give some more details on the model. This seems like a good screening exam question, where the examiner is simply waiting for the examinee to realize that dependence/independence information is important, and wants to know how comfortable the examinee is with working on an incomplete model and/or jumping to conclusions about independence (and about 0 or nonzero probability values).